# HTTP Digest with hashed stored password

Tags: security, http, tomcat, spring-security

i m using HTTP Digest to connect to my Spring application, using the Spring DigestAuthenticationFilter.
The application is using Tomcat 7.
It works fine with plaintext password (in the database)

My problem is : i want to store the hashed passwords (with a salt if possible), and not in plaintext. But if i understood well, HTTP Digest requires the password to be in plaintext.

Is there a way to change this in Spring Security ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> i want to store the hashed passwords
>   (with a salt if possible), and not in
>   plaintext. But if i understood well,
>   HTTP Digest requires the password to
>   be in plaintext.
>
> Is there a way to change this in
>   Spring Security ?

No, this is not changeable, atleast at the time of writing this. The [Spring Security documentation on Digest Authentication](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/2.0.x/reference/digest.html) states the following, where is it quite evident that the passwords have to be in clear text.

> The configured UserDetailsService is
>   needed because DigestProcessingFilter
>   **must have direct access to the clear
>   text password of a user**. Digest
>   Authentication will NOT work if you
>   are using encoded passwords in your
>   DAO.

Comment: would it be possible to extend the DigestAuthenticationFilter to make it possible ?

Comment: I'm not sure if that would work (for I haven't attempted this before), but it would be worth trying. You might also have to extened DigestProcessingFilterEntryPoint so that you can issue a WWW-Authenticate response header with a algorithm value that is not MD5, but supported by the browser. If the previous scheme of extending the classes don't work, you might also attempt a different approach of using a DelegatingFilterProxy, but I've never seen it used for Digest authentication.

Comment: Is there anyway to make a custom AuthenticationProcessingFilter to have `DigestEntryPoint` as its entry point so that you can access the username and password?